# Issue with menu background color in opera browser only

Tags: css, magento

i have set the background for menu and it is working fine in all the browsers except for opera. My css for the same is as:

```
#nav {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #2B0624, #CC0099) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    height: 51px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

can any one help me out in this:

Comment: -moz-linear-gradient is a Mozilla only style property.

Comment: Have a look at [http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)... This will support all common browsers

Comment: @XeeMezAsHu it's `-o-`, not `-op-` for Opera. Also, the latest Opera does support the version without the prefix. `linear-gradient`

Comment: @MrLister sorry my mistake.gone in the flow of -moz- ☺

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Golu use -o-linear-gradient and enjoy .

Comment: i did this very early gonchu